# How to lock row in Google Sheets after for ex. 5:00 PM

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to lock row in google sheets after exact day and time?
Both values will be in the sheet.
I would like to make it automated.
[image: This image represent my google sheet row]
I would love to block last two cels after exact date and time in the first two cels.

I watch several videos but didnt found any answear :/

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_s73sa5cKufLoFJkICOK9htY-KOk_lHfDG5xoZkD1S4/edit?usp=sharing here is exact table.
I wish for ex. to block cells H12:I12 after time in B12:C12 and so on.

Comment: possible with script

Comment: I know that it will be script. I know that this will also use some time triggers but I dont understand how it works :D

Comment: Could you provide us a sample of your data and how it's located in the Google Sheets, not as a screenshot but as actual data? It doesn't matter that the rest of the information in the row is dummy info, just keep the date information in the exact location they are in your data.  Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue.  Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_s73sa5cKufLoFJkICOK9htY-KOk_lHfDG5xoZkD1S4/edit?usp=sharing here is exact table.
I wish for ex. to block cells H12:I12 after time in B12:C12 and so on.

Comment: and it should be unblocked at midnight ? or what happens when the "block" time changes in the cell ?

Comment: @dzm11, I added sample code.

Comment: It should be never unblocked

Comment: What do you mean by it should never unblocked? If you mean that the protection of the cells should not get unblocked. It will not be removed until you deleted the protection manually or with a new code.

Comment: @dzm11. The trigger is to make sure that the cell is blocked/protected only after the time in the sheet has passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good answear is this

```
Link to sheet
const SHEETURL = ""

// Name of sheet
const SHEETNAME = ""

// Column with Data
const STARTCOLUMN = "B"

// Row with first occurence
const STARTROW = "62"

// Column with hours 
const ENDCOLUMN = "C"

// Last occurence
const ENDROW = "82"


const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SHEETURL)
const sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(SHEETNAME)
const range = sheet.getRange(STARTCOLUMN+STARTROW+":"+ENDCOLUMN+ENDROW)
const values = range.getDisplayValues()
const currentTime = new Date(Date.now() + 0)


function main() {

  values.forEach((row,i) => {
    try{
        const rowToBlock = parseInt(i + parseInt(STARTROW)).toString()
        const timestamp = row[0]+ " " + row[1]
        const parsedTs = Utilities.parseDate(timestamp,timeZone="GMT+0100",format="MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm")
        if(parsedTs <= currentTime){
          protectRow(rowToBlock)
        }
    }catch(e){
      Logger.log(e.message)
    }

    
  })
}

function protectRow(rowNumber){
  const protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)
  const rowToProtect = sheet.getRange(rowNumber,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn())

  for(p of protections){
    if(parseInt(p.getRange().getRow()) === parseInt(rowNumber)){
      return
    }
  }
  Logger.log("Blokuje zakres: " + rowNumber + " 1" + ":" + rowNumber + " " + sheet.getLastColumn())
  const protection = rowToProtect.protect()

  const me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code that will protect the range requested of H12:I12 and forward:

```
function testNew_2() {

  //variables to get information on the sheet, including the range with the date and time 
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Tabela wyników');
  let rangeDate = spreedsheet.getRange("B12:B").getValues().flat();
  let rangeTime = spreadsheet.getRange("C12:C").getValues().flat();

  // This will format the current time and date 
  //so the protected range will be based on the time of the sheet
  // not midnight of the current time
  let now_datetime = new Date();
  let now_date = now_datetime.toLocaleDateString();
  let now_time = now_datetime.toLocaleTimeString();
  let now = now_date + " "+  now_time;

  // filter and removes all the empty cells 

  rangeDate = rangeDate.filter((element) => {return (element !== '')});
  rangeTime = rangeTime.filter((element) => {return (element !== '')});

  // merge the cell with the time and the date 
  // and follow the same format as "now." 

  let rangeDateTime = rangeDate.map(function(value,idx){
    time_info = rangeTime[idx].toLocaleTimeString();
    date_info = new Date(value).toLocaleDateString();   
    let newDateObj = date_info + " "+ time_info;
    return newDateObj
  });

  // adds the protected rage. It will remove all the users 
  //except the one running the script

  for (let i = 0; i < rangeDateTime.length; i++) {
    let row = rangeDateTime[i];
   //range H12:I12 and forward
    let range = spreedsheet.getRange(i+12,8,1,2);
    if(row <= now){
      let protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
      var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
      protection.addEditor(me);
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
      if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Since the range of time is hourly, I will advise you to do a time trigger of running the code per hour. Like this:

[image]
**Reference:**

- [Working with Dates and Times](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates).
- [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)
- [Managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)